# Simplest way to concatenate objective-C strings and achieve grammatical correctness (with 'and' conjunction)

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring, grammar

What is the easiest and best way in Objective-C to combine a list (NSArray) of NSStrings into a single NSString separated by commas, with the grammatically correct terminal conjunction ", and " before the final item of the list?

```
NSArray *anArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"milk", @"butter", @"eggs", @"spam", nil];
```

From this array,  I want the NSString `@"milk, butter, eggs, and spam"`.

More generally, if the list is more than two items long, I want `", "` between every item except the last and second-to-last (which should have `", and "`). If the list is two items long, I want just the `' and '` with no comma.  If the list is one item long, I want the single string from the array.

I like something as simple as:

```
NSString *newString = [anArray componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

But this of course omits the 'and' conjunction.

Is there a simpler and/or faster Objective-C way than the following:

```
- (NSString *)grammaticallyCorrectStringFromArrayOfStrings:(NSArray *)anArray {
    if (anArray == nil) return nil;
    int arrayCount = [anArray count];
    if (arrayCount == 0) return @"";
    if (arrayCount == 1) return [anArray objectAtIndex:0];
    if (arrayCount == 2) return  [anArray componentsJoinedByString:@" and "];

    // arrayCount > 2
    NSString *newString = @"";
    for (NSString *thisString in anArray) {
        if (thisString != [anArray objectAtIndex:0] && thisString != [anArray lastObject]) {
            newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:@", "];
        }
        else if (thisString == [anArray lastObject]) {
            newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:@", and "];
        }
        newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:thisString];
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: An NSMutableString will help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the loop, I'd probably do something like

```
NSMutableString *newString = [NSMutableString string];
NSUInteger lastIndex = arrayCount - 1;
[anArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *thisString, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (idx != 0)
        [newString appendString:@","];
    if (idx == lastIndex)
        [newString appendString:@" and "];

    [newString appendString:thisString];
}];
```

Though I guess that's not really less lines.

Comment: Maybe not less lines, but easier to follow.